# Communicate microcontroller with smartphone via bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, microcontroller, atmega

I need do communicate atmega88 with a smartphone via bluetooth using a bluetooth HC-05 module. The problem is that all my atmega pins are being used. Rxd and txd pins are being used by a keypad (Keypad at PORTD). My project is almost done, at this stage i don't want to change the micro. Is there any alternative to solve this problem? Thanks

Comment: Please ask this type of questions in a network like following:
http://arduino.stackexchange.com/
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Software serial library for that controller. But it is better to connect HC-05 module to default UART pins.